# The qualifiers given by the Meiri

Tags: rabbis, rishonim, geonim

Following [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/127607/what-is-the-reason-behind-the-meiri-intentionally-replacing-the-names-of-rabbis) post, quoting several qualifierss given by the Meiri to the Rabanim whose opinions he reports, I am interested to know if we have an exhaustive list, because some of are not reported in the list. I read also [this](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=40774#p=7&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=) list in the introduction of one edition of the Gittin's commentary, but it's also not exhaustive. Can someone give me the entire list?

See also [here](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=40776#p=5&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=).

[here](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/reader/reader.aspx?sfid=40778#p=4&fitMode=fitwidth&hlts=&ocr=).

I particularly search for גדולי האחרונים, and I think maybe the Rosh, but I don't know if the Meiri knew the Rosh.